# Grails Ajax callback not rendering/responding properly

Tags: json, ajax, rest, grails, groovy

I'm doing an ajax request to an own rest api and trying to print in an alert the message I get.
The point is I'm getting the following error:  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

The code that makes the call is:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"${g.createLink(controller:'report',action:'show')}",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            data: jSon,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(error)
        },
        complete: function() {
        }
    });
```

The return value i'm printing in the controller is:

```
JSON: {"results":"SELECT cliente.edad FROM Cliente cliente,Local local WHERE Local.numero==3 GROUP BY Cliente.edad ORDER BY Cliente.edad undefined""}
```

And what I'm doing in the controller is:

```
println "JSON: " + java.net.URLDecoder.decode((String)apiResponse.json)
    render java.net.URLDecoder.decode((String)apiResponse.json)
```

I have also tried with `respond` instead of `render` but same error

Comment: have you found the answer to your question. If yes then maybe answer your own question?

Comment: Please include the code you are using to query the database

Comment: Sadly i'm still dealing with it, I was preparing an exam. The problem is i'm getting the json properly at client side, but when I do an alert the message is "SyntaxError"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using render as JSON

```
def results = ['a':'AA','b':'BB']

render results as JSON
```

Comment: What i'm getting is:  `Cannot cast object '{"results":"SELECT cliente.edad FROM Cliente cliente,Departamente departamente WHERE Departamente.nombre==asdf GROUP BY row.grouping ORDER BY row.sorting undefined""}' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'grails.converters.JSON'`

Comment: This means you are trying to convert the wrong thing. Please include the code you are using to query the database.

Comment: also it says that .edad or age is undefined please check your table if that exists. Which means try running this in something like sqldeveloper.